# Cannot access existing table from WCF Code

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
    try
    {
        string strSQLConnString = GetConnectionString(); 
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLConnString))
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("spFortesting", myConnection);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", varParam1);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", varParam2);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", varParam3);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param4", varParam4);
            myConnection.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                if (myReader.HasRows)
                {
                    dt.Load(myReader);
                }

                myReader.Close();
            }

            myConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
```

I am getting exception like 
 "The exception message is 'Could not find stored procedure 'spFortesting'."

1. All other existing Stored Procs are accessed correctly.
2. Connection string is common for all other SQL calls in the application.
3. 'spFortesting' is newly created StoredProc.
4. owner is 'dbo' I tried with dbo.spname as well
5. While I can access the Stored Proc and Tables which are newly created using SQL Mgmt Studio and the same credentials as in web.config, but not thru the code.

What could have been wrong.

Thanks in Advance,

Amit

Comment: This might sound rather obvious, but I would double check that the connection string matches the server and database in SSMS - output a message in your application with the connection string.

Comment: yes, both connection strings matches, same credentials, same db , same server

Comment: Do the signatures match - same number of parameters, same types?

Comment: Hall of kind of shame!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake! when i watched it very closely I found that connection strings are not matching, the connectionstring was being picked up from the other similar sounding virtual directory. System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
                     System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(@"\AppName");
and my appname on the deployed server was AppNameNew for some unkown reasons, since ages. With the name AppName there was another virtual folder and its web.config was pointing towards different database. 
Sorry for the inconvenience caused if any.

Cheers!!!
and a Happy new year

Comment: Don't worry, something similar has happened to me in the past.  Took me ages to diagnose and fix.  This is why I always recommend printing out variables or tracking them with the debugger to see if they contain the values they "ought to".